# DAOs and inheritance in domain

Tags: java, subclass, dao

Suppose a domain has an inheritance chain. For example, it could have a `Fruit` super class with possible subclasses being `Apple` and `Banana`. How could a corresponding DAO be formed ?

Comment: Are you asking for a high level answer, or a technology specific answer?

Comment: A high level answer. I'm confused as to how to apply the pattern as I'm used to having one DAO for each domain class.

Comment: I depends on technology. If you use JPA2 you don't need DAO-s. Just use JPA inheritance strategy.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda There is some debate on whether DAOs are necessary with JPA. One view is that if you swap datasources it would be useful to have an interface to swap implementations around.

Comment: But in this approach you're loosing JPA features. I've seen desighn where you needed 8 DAOs to save e.g. product order instead of casading saving and one `em.persist`. Just to have generic DAOs. There is usually so much datasource specific code that you'd rather won't switch from RDBMS to document DB or something just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) - one per concrete class. In practice however, you should make a generic DAO and then subclass this DAO whenever you have specific queries.